# Can remove space between box and underline for android TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I want to create TextInputLayout without a gap between the underline and edge of the box
can remove this gap?

image here:

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tilSearch"
    android:hint="@string/search_location"
    app:errorEnabled="false"
    app:errorTextColor="@color/red"
    app:helperTextEnabled="true">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60dp"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: set background EditText = null

Comment: not work, your solution hide underline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my issue using scaleX attribute `android:scaleX="1.02"`. There might be some better way, but I couldn't find any.

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tilSearch"
            android:hint="@string/search_location"
            app:errorEnabled="false"
            app:errorTextColor="@color/red"
            app:helperTextEnabled="true">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_60dp"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:scaleX="1.02"
                android:inputType="text"
                tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[attr_android:scaleX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZcUn.png)

This will be the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZcUn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can actually remove this underline using these attributes instead removing gap. removing gap will create double line into the layout. so instead remove that gap remove underline in the editText..

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilSearch"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/search_location"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="@null"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                app:errorEnabled="false"
                app:errorTextColor="@color/red"
                app:helperTextEnabled="true">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:importantForAutofill="no"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```